# Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400

Tags: graphql

My brain broke. Why server send this error.I looked through all the articles with the same error and did not find a solution. What is the problem? How i can fixed this error? Please help.
My code.

**App.jsx**
This is client for Apollo Client

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/api/",
  request: (operation) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ""
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**signUp.js** 
This is mutation for sighUp

```
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";

export default gql`
  mutation signup($firstName: String!, $secondName: String!, $email: String!, $password: String! ) {
    signup(firstName: $firstName, secondName: $secondName, email: $email, password: $password ) 
  }
`;
```

**RegForm.jsx** 
It is my component registration

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Field, reduxForm, SubmissionError} from 'redux-form'
import regForm from './RegForm.module.css'
import { matchInput, passLength, email, required} from '../../../utils/validators'

import RegMutation from '../../../queries/signup'
import Button from '../../../UI/Button/Button'
import myInput from '../../../UI/Input/Input'
import { withMutation } from "react-apollo";

const passwordValidator = passLength(8);


class RegForm extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

    handleSubmit(fields) {
      console.log('Fields from handleSubmit',fields);

      const { mutate } = this.props;

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mutate({
          variables: {
            firstName: fields.loginField,
            email: fields.email,
            password: fields.passwordField
          }
        })
          .then(res => {
           console.log(res.data);
            resolve(res);
          })
          .catch(e => {
            reject(new SubmissionError({ _error: e?.message }));
          });
   });
  }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
            <form 
                className={regForm.formContent}
                onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit)}
            >

            <Field 
                name='loginField'
                type='text'
                component={myInput}
                validate={[required]}

            />
            <Field 
                name='email'
                type='text'
                component={myInput}
                validate={[email]}

            />
            <Field 
                name='passwordField'
                type='password'
                component={myInput}
                validate={[passwordValidator]}
                placeholderText='Введите пароль'
            />
            <Field 
                name='repPas'
                type='password'
                component={myInput}
                validate={[matchInput]}

            />
            <Button
                onClick={this.Click}
                className={regForm.button}>Sign Up
            </Button>

        </form>

        {this.props.error ? <span>{this.props.error}</span> : null}
        </div>
        )
    }
}
const connectedToReduxForm = reduxForm({
  form: "loginForm",
});



export default withMutation(RegMutation)(connectedToReduxForm(RegForm))
```

Comment: When you fill out the form, you receive the response 400 error?

Comment: A 400 response code means your query was invalid or otherwise malformed. Please review the raw response from your server in your browser's dev tools -- it should include an `errors` array with details about what exactly is wrong with you query.

Comment: I ran into a similar situation with a 400 error and was able to debug by looking for and reading the errors array in the network tab. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

secondName field is absent. I've known about this one by running full the project)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MR8R.png)